# Why is BitSet not Iterable?

Tags: java, iterable, bitset

`BitSet` has a `stream()` method but it does not implement the `Iterable` interface like other types that provide this method. Is there a specific reason for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None of the methods in `Iterable` (`foreach`, `iterator`, and `spliterator`) is provided in `BitSet`. There is no `stream()` method in `Iterable`.

Furthermore the `stream()` method of `BitSet` does not return a stream over the bits of the bit set, but returns a stream over the *indices of the bits whose values are set* (which is kind of confusing TBH). Therefore, technically speaking there seems to be almost nothing in common with `Iterable`.

Answer (score 5):

One reason (not the entire reason, maybe) is that `Iterable` would inefficient, because the bit indexes have to be boxed (*); the stream is able to use primitive ints.

There's an efficient way to iterate the bitset without using `Iterable`, as described in the Javadoc, so it's not really necessary.

---

(*) However, for bitsets with size 128 or smaller, boxing would be cheap, as cached boxed instances would be used.

Answer (score 3):

`BitSet` is not a "true" member of the java collection framework, so technically, no need to implement `Collection.iterator()` and provide one.

```
public class BitSet implements Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

More to the point, both would be ill-fitted togethoer.

BitSet are not *generic*, unlike java.util.Iterator; BitSet provides ad-hoc methods with special features for side-effects and random addressing, unlike Iterator.

Answer (score -1):

Probably to avoid expensively boxing every bit to a `Boolean` instance.

Looping over it using its own APIs will avoid all allocations.

Comment: could be a primitive short i guess

Comment: @fabienbk: No; Java does not support primitive generics.

Comment: Boxing to a Boolean is really cheap: there's only two of them, and they're cached. The `stream` returns `int`s representing the set bit indexes; I think OP expects the `Iterable` to do the same (except with `Integer`).

Comment: Oops, you're right. Definitely the main reason then.

Comment: Java does have PrimitiveIterator since 8, so it could have been possible I guess

Comment: No, it's just an odd duck class that pre-dates Collections. It has methods with names that are at odds with collections conventions too (take a look at size). It's not related to performance, it's just a somewhat abandoned class.

Comment: "a somewhat abandoned class" citation needed. In my experience, it's not abandoned, but rather only used in specific applications.

Comment: @AndyTurner Look at its use in the JDK - occasional use in some older classes. The problem with it is it makes no useful performance and storage guarantees and has a weird old API. Anyone needing a bitset is likely to use something else or a newer third party implementation.

Comment: @pvg: it got additions in 1.2, 1.4, 1.7 and 1.8. That’s not the typical pattern of a “somewhat abandoned class”. The use within the JDK itself is irrelevant, I could point to lots of classes not being used within the JDK itself. And what “useful performance and storage guarantees” do you expect? The storage is one bit per bit, plus an implementation specific padding. And why should `BitSet` be the first class in the entire Java history making “performance guarantees”?

Comment: @Holger many java classes have specified performance characteristics. 'one per bit plus padding' is not really stated by the docs, even if that does happen to be the implementation. In the end, for trivial cases you're more likely to use a raw mask or an array or collection of booleans, for not-trivial cases, there are piles of other, better implementations. If you don't like 'abandoned' I guess 'vestigial' is a better word.